# How to verify replication data integrity in SQL Server when using external replication engine

Tags: sql-server, replication, data-integrity

I am looking for a way to verify that data I am replicating between SQL Server databases is making it to the destination OK.

Data is being replicated using an external replication engine, no built-in SQL Server replication.

Looked into using SQL Server's `CHECKSUM` and `CHECKSUM_AGG` but those functions do not work well with tables with millions of records.

I am thinking that a scalable solution would divide tables into chunks and compare those.

Comment: Questions about which tool to use are generally off-topic in DBA.SE. If you'd like to ask about how to accomplish the functionality yourself I'd suggest editing the question as such, otherwise it may get closed as it stands.